# Problems with PayPal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

just wondering if someone can help me with a frustrating problem I am having regarding PayPal IPN. My Code is:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // tell PHP to log errors to ipn_errors.log in this directory
    ini_set('log_errors', true);
    ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');

    // intantiate the IPN listener
    include('ipnlistener.php');
    $listener = new IpnListener();

    // tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
    $listener->use_sandbox = false;

    // try to process the IPN POST
    try {
       $listener->requirePostMethod();
       $verified = $listener->processIpn();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       error_log($e->getMessage());
       exit(0);
    }

    // TODO: Handle IPN Response here
    // ... 

    if ($verified) {
       echo 'hello';
       // TODO: Implement additional fraud checks and MySQL storage
       mail('my email here', 'Valid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
    } else {
       // manually investigate the invalid IPN
       mail('my email here', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
    }
```

?>

My ipnlistener.php is the one given here: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

When someone submits a payment, I do get the Valid IPN e-mail as I should in the code, but nothing else is echoed (i.e. the hello does not echo), and the footer of my page is not there. It's like to refuses to echo anything but does follow the rest of the commands. In my errors log, I always get 'Invalid HTTP request method.'

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Edit: Just incase it helps to know, anything echoed before

```
try {
   $listener->requirePostMethod();
   $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   error_log($e->getMessage());
   exit(0);
}
```

is fine, but anything echoed after does not work.

Comment: Error where? On the page I get no error at all, it prints my header in html, but as soon as it reaches the PHP part, everything stops, except I still get the Valid IPN e-mail. In the error_log, I get 'Invalid HTTP request method.'

Comment: make sure that `$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";` this added to your header

Comment: tell me where have you set the header for paypal

Comment: My header is currently:    `$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";`

Comment: The header is inside the ipnlistener.php file. If you go to https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN and have a look at the file, mine is an exact copy. I have not edited anything on it.

Comment: oh i am so sorry i havent used curl for paypal yet i did  only simple i have to read about that hope you will get help soon and me too

Answer (score 0):

The "Invalid HTTP request method" error is intentionally thrown by requirePostMethod(). The idea is that this page should only accept POST requests. When you view the page in your browser, it's a GET request.

Edit : When requirePostMethod() throws the exception, this stops PHP from parsing the rest of the page, which is why things afterwards don't get echoed out.

Check out the comments on requirePostMethod on GitHub => https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/blob/master/ipnlistener.php (It's right at the bottom).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like you might be able to help me which is fantastic. I've read the comment and I've understood why it happens, but I'm not sure how to change it so that it will parse the rest of the page?

Comment: I've managed to get it to use a post request, but now I get an error of 'headers already sent' caused by the `header('Allow: POST', true, 405);` line. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Simply take out $listener->requirePostMethod(). The class method doesn't seem to be used by anything else and is there just to make sure your script only accepts POST requests. If you want to allow GET requests, then there is no need to use the function. But, I would suggest that if you're just debugging the script that you put the line back in when it goes live (it's good for security).